# Linking one field of a model to another by queryset

Tags: python, django

I have a session variable that stores the ID of a model. I would now like to filter query sets by the name of the model instead of the id. Currently it only filter by the ID that it compares to the name. How can I get it to use the name instead of ID.

**Template link**

```
<td><a class="btn btn-info" href="{% url 'nodisoapp:select' company.id  %}">Working Page</a></td>
```

**Urls**

```
url(r'^select/(?P<company_id>\d+)/$', views.comp_select, name='select'),
```

**view1**

```
def comp_select(request, company_id):
    request.session['company'] = company_id
    return redirect('nodisoapp:working',company_id)
```

**Filter View**

```
class LeadListView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
     login_url = '/scrty/login/'
        template_name = "nodiso/leadslist.html"
        model = models.Leads
        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            ctx = super(LeadListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            ctx['company']= models.Company.objects.all()
            return ctx
        def get_queryset(self):
            return models.Leads.objects.filter(company=self.request.session['company'])
```

**Parent Model**

```
class Company(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=265, blank=True)
    tel = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=265,blank=True)
    address = models.TextField(blank=True)
    postal = models.TextField(blank=True)
    regno = models.CharField(max_length=265,blank=True)
    vatno = models.CharField(max_length=265,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('nodisoapp:home')
```

**Child Model**

```
class Leads(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=265)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=265)
    tel = models.IntegerField()
    dateenq = models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('nodisoapp:leadlist')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

```
def comp_select(request, company_id):
    comp = models.Company.objects.get(id=company_id)
    request.session['company'] = comp.name
    request.session['compid'] = company_id
    return redirect('nodisoapp:working',company_id)
```